# Derivative of a function defined by integral

Tags: calculus, integration, derivatives

This question popped up somewhere on the internet and I thought it was interesting. I attempted to solve it but I don't know if it is correct.

> Find the derivative of $$F(x)=\int_{\cos{x^3}}^{\int_{1}^{x} {1/(1+t^2)dt}} {\sin{w} dw}$$

$$\begin{align}
\implies F(x) & =-\cos{w}]_{\cos{x^3}}^{\arctan{x}-\frac{\pi}{4}}\\ 
& = -\cos{(\arctan{x}-\frac{\pi}{4})}+\cos{(\cos{x^3})}\\
\implies F'(x) & = \frac{1}{1+x^2} \sin{(\arctan{x}-\frac{\pi}{4}})+3x^2\sin{(x^3)} \sin{(\cos{(x^3)})}\\
\end{align}$$

Is it this simple? Or is there something I should know before solving this that changes the normal differentiation and integration techniques?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, it's that simple. Though, perhaps, you were meant to use the formula $$\frac{d}{dx}\left[\int_{a(x)}^{b(x)}f(t)\,dt\right]=b'(x)f(b(x))-a'(x)f(a(x))$$ which holds for continuous $f$ and differentiable $a$ and $b$.

Another possible simplification is using the identities $\cos\arctan x=\frac{1}{\sqrt{1+x^2}}$ and $\sin\arctan x=\frac{x}{\sqrt{1+x^2}}$ and expanding the various $\cos(\arctan x+\alpha)$ and $\sin(\arctan x +\alpha)$.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, your concept is correct. But note that we have 
$$
F(x) = \int_{g(x)}^{f(x)}\sin w dw = \int_{a}^{f(x)} \sin w dw - \int_{a}^{g(x)} \sin w dw 
$$
where $f,g$ are the given functions appearing in the original upper and lower integral limits, respectively; note that $f,g,F$ are "nice" enough to allow us to write
$$
DF(x) := F'(x) = D\int_{a}^{f(x)}\sin w dw - D\int_{a}^{g(x)} \sin w dw = \sin \circ f(x)f'(x) - \sin \circ g(x)g'(x) 
$$
for all suitable $x$ by the chain rule.